# Using the Maxmind geo IP database without GeoIP PECL extension?

Tags: php, geo

I'm trying to upload my files on free webhosting, to trial. I'm getting a problem with the output of client ip locator. I'm using maxmind database. "GeoIP.dat"

`<?php
print geoip_database_info(GEOIP_COUNTRY_EDITION);
?>`

and the output is

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function geoip_database_info() in /home/u_fg176/public_html/index.php on line 15`

Is it the function `geoip_database_info()` not found because this hosting doesn't install pecl ext for php? Or could there be another cause of this error?

Answer (score 2):

It's indeed because your host didn't install the PECL extension. You can use the somewhat [equivalent PEAR extension Net_GeoIP](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_GeoIP) instead, which is written in PHP and can simply be included in your project:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/path/to/Net_GeoIP');
require_once 'Net_GeoIP/Net/GeoIP.php';

$GeoIP = Net_GeoIP::getInstance(GEOIP_COUNTRY_EDITION);
$location = $GeoIP->lookupLocation($ipAddress);
```

Comment: thanx for your help... im working in windows, do you mea that i must download pyrus.phar file and install it under my project folder and upload in this hosting??

Comment: No, I mean that you download the PHP source from Download > "Download For manual installation only" (http://download.pear.php.net/package/Net_GeoIP-1.0.0.tgz).

Comment: ok, i just download but i still got error `Warning: fopen(106) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u_fg176/public_html/Net/GeoIP.php on line 425 

Fatal error: Uncaught <table st....` is it seems that GeoIP.dat can't open? how to solve this? i place GeoIP.dat in folder /Net/GeoIP/ is it true??

Comment: I was assuming `GEOIP_COUNTRY_EDITION` is the location of the database. Call `Net_GeoIP::getInstance` with the path to the database, it doesn't matter where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that would be the reason. Ask them to enable or extension, or look for an alternative if they don't cooperate.

Comment: The alternative is what @deceze mentioned. Include the files yourself in your project.